# Vulkan error: must write gl_Position

Tags: c++, vulkan

**Hello!**

I have followed this tutorial about Vulkan: https://vulkan-tutorial.com. But the problem is that when I start my application, this error came:

```
Validation layer: Vertex info
-----------
(0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position

Failed to create graphics pipeline
```

This happens when the graphics pipeline got created too.
I only found answer for OpenGL but not for Vulkan.
I tried to rewrite the code that reads the file but nothing.
Here the code of VkShader.cpp (contains the Shader Module)

```
IOManager::FIOManagerFile shaderCode = IOManager::ReadBinaryFile(filename);

vk::ShaderModuleCreateInfo createInfo = vk::ShaderModuleCreateInfo()
    .setCodeSize(shaderCode.Size)
    .setPCode(reinterpret_cast<const uint32*>(shaderCode.Contents));

if (context->GetDevice().createShaderModule(&createInfo, nullptr, &ShaderModule) != vk::Result::eSuccess)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create shader module for shader " + filename);
}
```

and IOManager.h

```
struct FIOManagerFile
{
    size_t Size;
    char* Contents;
};

static inline FIOManagerFile ReadBinaryFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::ate | std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        size_t fileSize = (size_t)file.tellg();
        char *buffer = new char[fileSize];
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(buffer, fileSize);
        file.close();

        FIOManagerFile f;
        f.Size = fileSize;
        f.Contents = buffer;
        return f;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file " + filename);
    }
}
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: What gpu, driver and os? That message does not look like your typical validation layer message and the code is also not defined in the database of validation layer errors, so this may be a message from the driver instead.

Comment: Nvidia GeForce 1050 Ti using Windows 10 Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that the file IO code has anything to do with this error.  It sounds like you're not attaching a vertex shader to the pipeline, or that you've compiled the GLSL for the vertex shader incorrectly.

When compiling the GLSL to Spir-V your vertex shader input file should have the extension `.vert` or you need to specify on the command line that you're compiling a vertex shader.  When building the graphics pipeline you need to, at minimum, add two shader modules, one vertex shader and one fragment shader, each using a `vk::PipelineShaderStageCreateInfo` to wrap the shader modules you're creating.

Comment: I've done all of that, my vertex shader have the .vert extension, I have `vk::PipelineShaderStageCreateInfo` for the vertex & fragment shader that are grouped in a array. And used here: `.setPStages(ShaderProgram.GetShaderStages())`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps forget to assign a value to `gl_position` in your shader?  Your vertex shader should have some lines like:

```
void main() {
      gl_Position = mvp * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
}
```

If this is not it, could you post your vertex shader code?